# Can i get the user's friend's phone number using graph api?

Tags: api, object, facebook-graph-api, phone-number

I want to make facebook web apps using Graph API. I finished tutorial about Graph API, and I have a question.

My app must get the user's friend's phone number but in the `user` object, the phone number field does not exist.

How can I get the user's friend's phone number??

Comment: Are you talking about a mobile web application or a desktop web appliation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is not possible by the moment, please check the following link:

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/447/

Despite it's quite old, nothing new has been heard.